# getElementByid in Javascript when element ID contains Dollar sign

Tags: javascript

getElementById() does not appear to find the element when the ID contains a dollar sign. Is there a way around this in pure Javascript? I have no control over the element ID's as these are generated by a "page builder" and I cannot use jQuery in this application.

Example:

```
<div id="win0divFRED$0">
```

```
var orig = document.getElementById("win0divFRED$0");
```

Many Thanks,
John

Comment: works fine http://jsfiddle.net/XKn5X/

Comment: Works fine for me - there should be no problem.

Comment: Works fine for me too : http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/Chtkj/

Comment: may depend on the  doctype i guess, try the new one:`<!doctype html>`

Comment: Many thanks for such fast responses. Alas, doesn't work in my world and the answer from Christoph regarding the doctype is probably the reason why. I can't change from HTML4.01 as the pages are generated by an application I have no control over. The pages are generated with a mixture of tokens, some contain dollar signs and some do not. getElementByid finds the non-dollar elements fine, but not those containing a dollar sign in the ID.

Answer (score 2):

Since the HTML4.01 spec is pretty restrictive

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

your id would be invalid according to 4.01 spec.
In contrast to HTML5:

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

I think it might be a problem with the doctype. Try:

```
<!doctype html>
```